# Scaling up an Image in C - most efficient way

Tags: c, image-processing

I wrote a function to scale an image from 32x24 Pixel to 320x240 Pixel. The image is from the MLX90640 IR-sensor and is actually an array of 768 floats. I already invested quite some time to make it as fast as possible, but wanted some input weather it can be made more efficient. The function consists of two parts:

1. Getting a Color equivalent from a Temperature Map by rounding the float to the nearest int and getting the RGB565 Color out of it

```
#define TEMPERATURE_MAP_SIZE 21

static const USHORT GRADIENT_MAP[TEMPERATURE_MAP_SIZE+20] =         //filler zeroes
{
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0x001f,         //Position 20 for 20degrees
    0x00dc,
    0x0199,
    0x0276,
    0x0333,
    0x0410,
    0x04cc,
    0x0589,
    0x0666,
    0x0723,
    0x07e0,
    0x1f20,
    0x3660,
    0x4d80,
    0x64c0,
    0x8400,
    0x9b20,
    0xb260,
    0xc980,
    0xe0c0,
    0xf800          //Position 40 for 40degrees
};

static inline USHORT get_gradient(uint_fast16_t val)
{
    if(val<20)return GRADIENT_MAP[20];
    if(val>40)return GRADIENT_MAP[40];
    return GRADIENT_MAP[val];
}
```

2. Calculating the Resized Pixelmap. It is meant to look 'pixelated', I don't want any smoothing, as such an algorithm would take up processor time again. The pixelmap data is a unsigned short (RGB565) array the size of (width x height).

```
#define RESIZE_FACTOR 10
#define RESIZE_FACTOR_SQUARED RESIZE_FACTOR*RESIZE_FACTOR
#define RESIZE_FACTOR_BY_COLUMN_NUM MLX90640_COLUMN_NUM*RESIZE_FACTOR
#define RESIZE_FACTOR_SQUARED_BY_COLUMN_NUM RESIZE_FACTOR_SQUARED*MLX90640_COLUMN_NUM

static inline void resize_pixelmap()
{
    USHORT *pixelmap_data_ptr,*pixelmap_resized_data_ptr;
    float *arr=get_ir_sensor_data_pointer();
    pixelmap_data_ptr=ir_icon_pixelmap_data;
    pixelmap_resized_data_ptr=ir_icon_pixelmap_resized_data;
    for(int x=0;x<MLX90640_LINE_NUM;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<MLX90640_COLUMN_NUM;y++)
        {
            pixelmap_data_ptr[MLX90640_COLUMN_NUM*x+y]=get_gradient((uint_fast16_t)roundf(arr[MLX90640_COLUMN_NUM*x+y]));
            for(int k=0;k<RESIZE_FACTOR;k++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<RESIZE_FACTOR;j++)
                {
                    pixelmap_resized_data_ptr[j+k*RESIZE_FACTOR_BY_COLUMN_NUM+y*RESIZE_FACTOR+x*RESIZE_FACTOR_SQUARED_BY_COLUMN_NUM]=pixelmap_data_ptr[MLX90640_COLUMN_NUM*x+y];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I #defined many calculations as preprocessor macros to save time. The pixelmap_data_ptr is the unresized data, pixelmap_resized_data_ptr is calculated from this one. With the factor set to 10, 1 pixel in the original image becomes 10 x 10 Pixels in the new image.

This algorithm works, but I think it could be optimized more. Maybe someone has an idea.

Comment: Your program never accesses the first 20 elements of GRADIENT_MAP[] so you could remove them and return GRADIENT_MAP[val-20] etc.

Comment: If this is working code, then you probably should've posted your question on the code review site instead. Generally speaking, when you have nested for statements, you only need to worry about optimising the innermost for. In this case, you could make it much more efficient by doing the index calculations beforehand that are known. e.g. k\*RESIZE_FACTOR_BY_COLUMN_NUM+y\*RESIZE_FACTOR+x\*RESIZE_FACTOR_SQUARED_BY_COLUMN_NUM and pixelmap_data_ptr[MLX90640_COLUMN_NUM\*x+y] are the same for all j.

Comment: @SimonGoater Is it faster when I have to do a subtraction to access the correct element everytime? Sorry for posting in the wrong Subsection, it's my first post here. I will review the index calculations and see if it brings more speed

Comment: Given where the function call is in your code, it won't make a noticeable difference either way, Computations are cheap, but memory access is expensive, so if you can halve the look-up table size, that's generally going to be a good idea.

Comment: It should be noted that your compiler may already have made the optimisations about the innermost for loop I suggested. You could look at the assembler to see what it does. Changing the code as I said should make it faster if compiled without optimisations, but it won't make it any faster if your compiler is already doing it.

Comment: @SimonGoater I also changed the element count of the gradient map, together with the indexing. I would say, it is a bit faster, but I will have to actually measure it to really tell the difference. Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: I haven't tested this idea, or written any C for about 9 years, but I wonder if you are messing up your cache by writing 10x10 pixels to the resized image for each input pixel. The first 10 will be adjacent in memory, then next 10 will be one image width away, the next 10 two image widths away. Maybe observe that the output image will have 10 rows the same, then 10 different rows all the same, then another 10 rows all the same. So, if you changed your code to generate just 1 line but 10 times wider for each line of input, you could then...

Comment: ...contd.... make a second pass in which you replicated each line 10x using something efficient like `memcpy()` to copy a whole row 10 times. Just a thought, and may not be worth investing too much effort. I presume you have turned on compiler optimisations, e.g. `-o3` and `-march=native`

Answer (score 1):

> I think it could be optimized more. Maybe someone has an idea.

Minor ideas:

**Round directly**

Rather than round and then convert FP to integer, perform both in one function.

```
// (uint_fast16_t)roundf(arr[MLX90640_COLUMN_NUM*x+y]);
(uint_fast16_t) lroundf(arr[MLX90640_COLUMN_NUM*x+y]);
```

**Fill 1st 20**

Rather than 0 in the first 20 array elements, copy element 20 to them and then drop `if(val<20)return GRADIENT_MAP[20];` test.

**Pre-compute**

Instead of `MLX90640_COLUMN_NUM*x` in the `y` loop, pre-compute `int numx = MLX90640_COLUMN_NUM*x`.  OTOH, a good compiler may effectively do that for code already.

Likewise for `k*RESIZE_FACTOR_BY_COLUMN_NUM+y*RESIZE_FACTOR+x*RESIZE_FACTOR_SQUARED_BY_COLUMN_NUM` and `pixelmap_data_ptr[MLX90640_COLUMN_NUM*x+y]`.  Pre-compute them before the loop.

**For deeper feedback**

Post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data on [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

> I think it could be optimized more. Maybe someone has an idea.

Presuming the objective is to simply display a range of distinctive colours to show approximate temperature differences, it might be slightly faster to simply truncate the `float` value(s), rather than seeking to round them, first. The desire is to show adjacent pixels distinctively coloured when the temp difference crosses a threshold.

Eg: the integer difference between 22° and 23° is the same as the difference between 22.8° and 23.8°.

The goal is to display difference, not absolute values. Invoking rounding is to suggest more accuracy than is justified (if you're primarily looking for speed.)

---

Given that this is likely an MCU project, there's no need to consider *cache* and the concern about *cache misses*.

---

As proposed by @MarkSetchell, the code would be much cleaner (and may run faster) if it used `memset()` to *replicate* each pixel horizontally, then `memcpy()` to replicate entire rows vertically. Let library functions perform loops that have been tuned for performance by experts.

---

Do you need/want the entire *miniature* version of the image? Perhaps there's an array (with its index calculations) that could be removed from the code by using a single variable instead.

---

**EDIT:**
If the IR sensor's driver code is available, it would be worthwhile delving into it. Likely, `float` (in the MCU code) provides *generic* values because of some *scaling* or *curve fitting* of the raw **binary** data supplied by the sensor subsystem. Understanding what happens to that raw information (filling the array of `float`s) might enable you to achieve a similar effect in the realm of `int` arithmetic. (i.e. a table of acceptable integer coefficients for multiplication, or even a direct translation LUT.) There's no apparent requirement that `float` math needs to be involved.

I imagine the objective to be an image made of pixels showing **relative** temperature differences (i.e. not calibrated *absolute* temperatures). If so, once hardware corrections (the sensor's pixel discrepancies) have been accounted-for, images would be more dramatic using the full scale of target display colour ranges, especially if the min/max values of data cover only a small range of temperatures. Dynamically scaling the data would require a second pass over all the values, but this could be combined when "amplifying" the pixels from 32x24 to 320x240.